# Extracting empty arrays with akka and circe?

Tags: scala, akka, circe

I have a project in akka and circe.  I am currently sending this json in the response body:

```
{ "a": 33, "things": [{ "id1": ["2"], "id2": [], "id4": [], "id5": [] } ] }
```

I am trying to extract it to this case class:

```
  case class Body(things: Option[List[Things]])
  case class Things(id1: Option[List[String]] = None, id2: Option[List[String]] = None, id3: Option[List[String]] = None, id4:Option[List[String]] = None)
```

I am doing this using this code :

```
  entity(as[Body]).as(Body.getIds)
```

This code relies on the below companion object

```
  object Body extends ErrorAccumulatingCirceSupport {

    def getIds(body: Body): List[String] = 
      body.things.get.flatMap(_.id4.getOrElse(List()))
    }
```

However, unless I actually pass in a value in the objects within the things array (e.g. "id2": [ "33"])

It never finishes unmarshalling the json.  Grateful for any advice!